# Calculating area of two vectors. (problems with getting calculations correct)

Tags: linear-algebra, area

We have two vectors $u$ and $v$:
$$ u=-3i+5j+2k  $$
$$ v=4i+3j-3k  $$
Cross product $u\times v$ gives us:
$$u \times v =\begin{vmatrix}i & j & k \\ -3 & 5 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 & -3 \end{vmatrix} \\ =(5\times(-3)-2\times3)i \\ -(-3\times(-3)-4\times2)j \\ +(-3\times3-4\times5)k \\ u \times v =-21i-j-29k$$
these calculations on [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-3i%2B5j%2B2k)x(4i%2B3j-3k))

Now according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) area of two vectors $u$ and $v$ is $|u \times v|$ ($a$ and $b$ in this example)

[image: -||-]

So i can think of at least two good ways to determine area formed by vectors $u$ and $v$. These are:

$$ area_a=|u|\times|v| $$
$$ area_b=|u \times v|  $$

Now when i try to calculate area with these two methods. I get slightly different answers and i don't know why i would get two different areas ?
Calculated areas are:

$$ area_a = \sqrt{(-3)^2+(5)^2+(2)^2}\sqrt{(4)^2+(3)^2+(-3)^2}=2\sqrt{323}\approx35.95$$
$$ area_b = \sqrt{(-21)^2+(-1)^2+(-29)^2}=\sqrt{1283}\approx 35.82  $$

both areas should give same result?

$$ area_a=area_b$$

But in this these are different. Now if someone could point out what I am missing in these calculations or calculating wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: Your $area_a$ is not correct for non-rectangles.

Comment: About your notation: To avoid confusion, it might be better to use $·$ (`\cdot`) instead of $\times$ when you multiply scalars, and reserve $\times$ for the cross product of vectors.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I agree, but I suspect scalar multiplication vs. cross product is part of the OP's confusion.  Either that or they think the absolute value function is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These aren't *two* good ways. Only the second one is good. Why should the area be the product of the lengths of the vectors? That only happens when they're orthogonal, which is not the case here. Note that they are nearly orthogonal (the measure of the angle between them is about $94.8^\circ$). That's why the two numbers that you got are so close to each other.

Answer (score 2):

The area of two vector is $A=|\vec u |\,|\vec v| \sin\theta$

We have $$\cos \theta=\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{|\vec u |\cdot |\vec v|}$$

$$\cos\theta=-\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{323}}\to \sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1283}{323}}$$
So area is
$$A=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1283}{323}} \left(\sqrt{38} \sqrt{34}\right)=\sqrt{1283}$$
Like the other formula

Hope this helps